# position menu collapse icon to right of menu

Tags: bootstrap-4

I'm using a bootstrap 4 collapsable menu and I'm trying to get the collapse button to appear to the right of the menu, but without it taking space. Almost as if it were floating. The problem I'm having is that it's pushing everything to the right. If I use position:absolute, it won't shift left with the menu. Aney help is appreciated.

Thanks

Angel

```
<div id="wrapper">
<nav id="sidebar">  
      <ul class="list-unstyled components">                   
      </ul>
</nav>
    
<i class="fa fa-dedent collapseButton" id="sidebarCollapse"></i>

<content>
```